# How can I represent "fast" or "Fastest" in a logo? Any successful examples?

Tags: logo, branding, conceptualization

I am doing rebranding of a company that provides internet through fiber-optic cables.

I want to portray "FAST", "fiber optics" and "connectivity" in that logo.
In all my initial sketches, I  have catered the later two but not the first.

If you can provide link to your own or any other work which represents this then it will be highly helpful.

Much Thanks.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but you might find some inspiration in this question: [How can I represent speed in a graphic?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/29399/8708)

Comment: I saw that, the suggestions were more for an artwork.
I need that to depict in a logo so i do require more sophisticated techniques for it.

Comment: A picture of Speedy Gonzales. Can't go wrong with that.

Comment: A [google image search for 'fast logo'](https://www.google.com/search?q=fast%20logo&gws_rd=ssl&tbm=isch) contains tonnes of useful examples.

Comment: @Joonas Well, you know, other than being sued for copyright infringement. :)

Comment: I would advice against names and logos implying fast or so. Technologies change and you eventually are going to be the not so fast brand... Lots of examples available.

Comment: Here is an example... Did you see it? Just a joke. I could not help it XoD

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways you can represent "fast" in a logo. One way is to "italicize" the logo (text and/or graphics) which conveys movement. The more you angle the content, the more speed is implied. However, too much angling could distort your work.

Adding lines behind the movement might help. See GiantCowFilms example for this.

You might also consider only angling part of the logo, especially if it naturally fits that part of the logo. Italicizing words like "express" or "fast," if part of the company name would imply speed.

[image]

Another approach might be to add a slogan or other text that can imply (or outright state) that the company is fast.

[image]

Finally, you can find a symbol that gives the impression of the company being fast. Jets are a great approach but often do not fit the company's business. Think of other ways you could show "fast," even if they are not entirely realistic.

[image]

*Attribution: The hand extending from the computer monitor design was downloaded from [FreeVectorArt.net](http://www.freevectors.net/download/5659). It is being used under the [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/). It was designed by [Vector Open Stock](http://www.vectoropenstock.com).*

I hope these ideas help.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Something like this should get you started. The key is to imply motion by making the text appear to be trying to go somewhere. and because we read from left to right, make go from left to right. Otherwise it will appear to be moving "backwards".

<sup>Note: the graphic is awful looking, but it is there to demonstrate a concept.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
And the graphic is ok, It really helped me in understanding your point.:)

Answer (score 9):

FedEx uses the arrow in their design:
[image: FedEx logo with highlighted arrow]

As other people point out *italics* often represent speed as well.

Here's an image I found googleing for things that might help.

[image]

This combines an arrow moving right (The direction that it is being read) with speed lines on the left (again, the direction it is being read.)  In addition, the word "*express*" is in italics, sloping right (The direction the text would be going.)

Comment: Wow. I have never noticed that FedEx arrow before. Even has it in the Arabic version, right to left. :) http://www.designer-daily.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/fedex-arabic-logo-design1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you have figured out the "fibre optics" and "connectivity" part then fast should technically be easier with 
- a speedometer(with light green for fast n dark-green for fastest) 
- provided you know the units of your services.

Rest is, up to your imagination, how you intend to integrate this with your first two components.

Comment: The problem with a speedometer these days is that it is often used for "dashboards".

Answer (score 1):

You can do something with an image of a running figure, such as this one of Hermes. (Courtesy of Google image search)

[image: Hermes]

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated by other users, the use of italics represents movement. As implied by Umberto Eco in the SIGN PRODUCTION MODEL (http://www.signosemio.com/eco/modes-of-sign-production.asp) ,vectors demonstrate movement, any lines crossing through or skewing type will help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a check on this site: www.fastweb.it 
Their logo combine the idea of fiber optics and high speed connection. Also the direction that the whole logo suggests aims high, as if he wanted to communicate that he actually is at the top of his market field.
It fits perfectly your case. Sometimes looking at the competitors could be a good start.